# Преобразование к boolean

Tags: javascript

Дан пустой массив `a = []`. Выражение `console.log(a == !a)` возвращает `TRUE`. Я не совсем понимаю почему. `!a` понятно преобразуется к `FALSE`. Пустой массив `a`, по идее, преобразуется к `TRUE`.(`Boolean([])` возвращает `TRUE`) Получается `TRUE == FALSE ==> FALSE` / но результат `TRUE`. Что я упустил?

Спасибо!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Это потому что

```
console.log([].toString() === "") //true
```

вот немного  пруфа

```
Array.prototype.toString = function() {
 return this.join(",") || true;   
}
var a =[];
console.log(a == !a) // false :)
```

http://jsfiddle.net/od9p4nh5/1

кстати, из всего вышесказанного следует, что

```
[0] == false //true
[0] == "" // false
[] ==  "" // true
```